# Phoenix/Erlang node connection

Tags: concurrency, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, distributed-computing

I have an Elixir Phoenix node started on one machine and an Erlang node on another. The Erlang node has a process named "rec", that accepts a tuple of three elements: an atom and two charlists. When I run this code on the Elixir node:

```
Node.spawn_link(node_name, fn -> send(:rec, {:create, uuid, link}) end)
```

it runs as needed, but when I run it from the Phoenix controller, it returns an error like this:

```
[error] Error in process #PID<14185.2561.0> on node :"node1@192.168.0.137" with exit value:
{:undef, [{#Function<0.87309885/0 in SlrRecorderApiWeb.CameraController.add/2>, [], []}]}
```

What should I do to run it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the module `SlrRecorderApiWeb.CameraController` is not loaded on the Erlang node in question: when you're sending an `fn` function to be run on another node, the module where it is defined must be loaded on both nodes.

The good news is that you don't need to use a function here, you can just use:

```
send({:rec, node_name}, {:create, uuid, link})
```

and the message will be sent to the process named `rec` on the other node.

Comment: *when you're sending an `fn` function to be run on another node, the module where it is defined must be loaded on both nodes.* -- How can an anonymous function be defined in a module?

Comment: @7stud The anonymous function is considered to be "defined" in the module where the code for it appears. In fact, the VM even records which named function the anonymous function was defined in. In the error message we see `#Function<0.87309885/0 in SlrRecorderApiWeb.CameraController.add/2`, which refers to an anonymous function with arity 0 defined inside the function `add/2` in the module `SlrRecorderApiWeb.CameraController`.